# How to reset a for loop and also simplify it?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement, processing

say i have 4 variables:

```
int counter = 0;
int counter2 = -6;
int counter3 = -12;
int counter4 = -18;
```

These 4 variables increase in a certain if statement that fires from time to time as such:

```
if (such and such)
{
    counter++;
    counter2++;
    counter3++;
    counter4++;
}
```

and in order these draw circles around the screen in rows, so counter draws circles in the first row, and once that row is filled, counter2 fills the second row and so on:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    ellipse(ScoreX+ i * 80, 40, BallSize, BallSize);
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < counter2; j++)
  {
    ellipse(ScoreX + j * 80, 120, BallSize, BallSize);
  }
for (int k = 0; k < counter3; k++)
  {
    ellipse(ScoreX + k * 80, 200, BallSize, BallSize);
  }
for (int l = 0; l < counter4; l++)
  {
    ellipse(ScoreX + l * 80, 280, BallSize, BallSize);
  }
```

My problem is that once the circles have been drawn all over the screen, I want this whole process to reset and keep happening until the program has been manually closed by me.

What i mean by this is that, the program will know that counter4 (the last row of circles) has filled up the space with circles and once the last row is filled up, the program resets this whole process going back to filling row one.

Also, is there a way that this loop can be simplified?

EDIT: I found a way to restart it with a simple if statement as such:

```
if (counter4 == 7)
  {
    counter = 0;
    counter2 = -6;
    counter3 = -12;
    counter4 = -18;
  }
```

Comment: Assuming this is done in a separate thread to not block the GUI thread, just create an infinite loop (and add a sleep if needed).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it :

```
public class drawCircles implements Runnable{ //To run it in background

private boolean running; //This variable is used to know when thread should be stopped
private int counter = 0; //Here are your counters
private int counter2 = -6;
private int counter3 = -12;
private int counter4 = -18;
private int BallSize;
private int ScoreX;

public drawCircles(int _BallSize, int _ScoreX)
{
    running = true;
    BallSize = _BallSize;
    ScoreX = _ScoreX;
}

private void draw(int counter, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        ellipse(ScoreX + i * 80, value, BallSize, BallSize);
    }
}

public void run()
{
    while (running)
    {
        draw(counter, 40);
        draw(counter2, 120);
        draw(counter3, 200);
        draw(counter4, 280);
    }
}

public void terminate()
{
    this.running = false;
}

}
```

You can call `terminate()` when the window is about to get closed, to end the `thread`.

I also put your loop in function, to avoid code duplication. Just send the counter you need to it, and also the value that changes (I don't what this is used for, so I called it `value` in the code).

In case you need to modify the counters or any other values contained in `DrawCircles,` when the `if` statements are fired for example, just declare `setters`.

Making this class implementing `Runnable` is used to make it run in background. The only thing you need to know, now, is how to start it. See [here](http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-the-runnable-interface-in-java-to-create-and-start-a-thread/).

It might not exactly fit your needs, as I don't have all information, but I think that's a good start.

Comment: I get an error as such: Illegal modifier for the local class drawCircles; only abstract or final is permitted

Comment: @Aaryan did you declare `drawCircles` in another class?

Comment: But where did you copy/past it?

Comment: in an empty sketch.. was I not meant to do that

Comment: What I meant is that you must **not** copy/past in an existing class. It has to be in a new file for example

Comment: Yes, i opened up processing.exe from the windows taskbar.. a complete new sketch

Comment: Try removing `public` keyword from first line

Comment: I still get an error as such: The type drawCircles is never used locally

Comment: That's probably a warning, not an error, meaning you are never calling the class you're building. But did you instiate drawCircles class?

Comment: I actually just copy pasted your code into an empty sketch to have a look.. is there something i was meant to do manually besides that? and what do you mean by "instiate"

Comment: DrawCircles will not call itself. You must call it, in order to start it. I've provided you a link to start it on my anwser. Have a look. Ho, and I meant instantiate but I was not able to edit my comment for some reason. Just typo mistake